# Word for "opening and closing the mouth?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The stranded fish were flapping desperately on the sand, their mouths
>   **closing and opening,** seeking for the water that wasn't there.

Is there's a word that means *opening and closing the mouth*? I thought of *gaping* but I think it only means keeping the mouth open?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idiomatic way of saying this is

> The stranded fish were flapping desperately on the sand, [**gasping for breath**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gasp+for+breath).

Answer (score 4):

To [gulp](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gulp): (from TFD)

> - to gasp, as if taking large drafts of a liquid.

Fish [gulping](http://www.fishchannel.com/setups/ponds/abnormal-fish-behavior.aspx) for air:

> - After feeding time all the other fish are on the surface gulping or gasping. Sometimes this happens later in the day as well.

( from www.fishchannel.com)

Answer (score 2):

The term for the action a fish uses to "gasp" for air is called **[buccal action pumping](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Buccal_pumping)**.  I am wrapping up a conservation biology degree with focus in fishery science at CSU.  Here's some information:

**dual pump**: buccal and opercular action operating in tandem drives water in a nearly continuous unidirectional flow across the gill curtain between them

- the suction phase begins with compressed buccal and opercular cavities and closed valves
- as the buccal cavity expands, the internal oral valves open and water moves into the buccal cavity and across the gill curtain
- during the force phase, the oral valve closes and water is forced out through the opercular valve

Source: https://www.shsu.edu/~bio_mlt/Chapter11.html

A good image of this action can be found [here](https://www.pathwayz.org/Node/Image/url/aHR0cHM6Ly9pLmltZ3VyLmNvbS9yc01Kd1RNLnBuZz8y):

[image]